# How to load fbx file with animation in wpf project

Tags: wpf, fbx, 3d-model

Title: Trouble Animating FBX File in WPF

Explanation: I'm encountering difficulties animating an FBX file within a WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) application. Despite trying various libraries like Assimp and Helixtool, I've been unsuccessful in achieving animation. The models load successfully but remain static without animation. I need assistance finding a solution to animate the FBX model within my WPF project.

Background Research: I've attempted to use different libraries, such as Assimp and Helixtool, to animate the FBX file in my WPF application. However, none of these attempts have been successful, and the model continues to load without animation. I've searched online for solutions but haven't found any that adequately address my issue.

Thank you for any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: It seems to [FPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) is a proprietary file format. You can either of convert it to other format.. for use it with HelixToolkit or investigate [unoficial description for this format from Blender](https://code.blender.org/2013/08/fbx-binary-file-format-specification) and write own solution.

Comment: i tried but only 3D model shown not any animation